# How to Remotely share and access my android phone screen like teamviewer

Tags: android, screenshot, remote-access, teamviewer

I want to share my device screen on server and remotely access it from server.
I have tried many ways like: **MediaProjection** , **setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)**.

In case of MediaProjection i get to know that we have to pass a surface and it will draw the whole screen in that surface. But i want to fetch a drawable or bitmap from that surface which i can share and also handle click from server, which will reflect on my android device(just like teamviewer do):

MediaProjection :

```
VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenCapture",
            mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight(), mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface()
            , null, null);
```

But using **VirtualDisplay** or **Surface**, i am not able to share this on server. Is there any other way to capture screen continuously and share it on server.

**setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)** :

```
View view = getView().getRootView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
```

but the problem with this is, that i can not capture the screen outside my application i.e. i don't have access to the parent view on which other views are rendered.

Also if i get access to the parent of all the views but, it will not recursively draw the content of its child.

My overall question is **Any way to capture the screen(outside my application), share it on server and handle the click?**